# Issues with returning Java methods called from inside of if/else statements outside of main

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, return, return-value

I'm trying to call a method which contains calls to two other methods inside of if/else statements. I want the user's input to dictate which method is called. The methods inside of the if/else statements work when they aren't inside of the statements. When I call them from the if/else statements nothing is returned and the program ends. Anyone know why?

Here's the method:

```
public String infixpostfix(String inf){

    boolean spellcheck = false;
    String type = null;
    String result = null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Is your input \"postfix\" or \"infix\"");
    type = scan.nextLine();
    while (spellcheck == false){
        if (type.equals("infix")||type.equals("postfix")){
            spellcheck = true;
        continue;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid option. \"postfix\" or \"infix\"");
        type = scan.nextLine();
    }
    if (type .equals("infix")){
        result = postfix(inf);
        System.out.println("The postfix is: ");
    }
    else if (type.equals("postfix")){
        result = infix(inf);
        System.out.println("The infix is: ");
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is the Main method (it's in the same program):

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        MyStack ugh = new MyStack();
        System.out.println("Enter the equation");
        String inf = scan.nextLine();
        ugh.infixpostfix(inf);
    }
}
```

Sample of input - output:

```
Enter the equation
ab*+
Is your input "postfix" or "infix"
postfix
The infix is:
```

Here is the method called in this instance:

```
public String infix(String inf){
    //a + b * c + ( d * e + f ) * g
    //into postfix. A correct answer is a b c * + d e * f + g * +

    MyStack<String> holder2 = new MyStack();
    String inf2 = inf.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    int equationindex = 0;

    String eq = null;

    for (int infindex = 0; infindex < inf2.length(); infindex++){
        boolean operand = false;
        if (Character.isDigit(inf2.charAt(infindex))||Character.isLetter(inf2.charAt(infindex))){
            operand = true;
        }

        if (operand == true){
            holder2.push(Character.toString(inf2.charAt(infindex)));
            continue;
        }
        else {
            String temp2 = holder2.pop();               
            String temp = holder2.pop();
            eq = ("(" + temp + inf2.charAt(infindex) + temp2 + ")");
            holder2.push(eq);
            continue;
        }
    }   
    return eq;
}
```

Comment: Oh if I'm not misunderstanding you, the point is to reset type to the next input. If the user's spelling matches the if statement the program moves on, but if not they have to re-enter a valid input.

Comment: since "The infix is" is printing, the program is clearly making it to where I intend for it to go. I really just don't understand why result = infix(inf) isn't being returned by the return statement.

Comment: Don't edit the answer into your question. The question stands as-is. Rather, if someone provides and answer that solves your problem, accept it by clicking the check mark next to it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Heard. I deleted the edit. I'd prefer I could delete this question because the fact is that the problem arose from me misunderstanding == vs .equals and forgetting to reformat my code after some trial and error before realizing the difference between the two. My question seems completely uninformative and should be deleted since it was essentially a brain fart unrelated to the problem I stated in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not printing out your result.

Change

```
System.out.println("The postfix is: ");
```

to

```
System.out.println("The postfix is: " + result);
```

and do the same for the infix.